# How to use hw acceleration on Rockchip CPU?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, debian

Based on Rockchips [info notes](https://www.friendlyelec.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=290):

[image]

Its VPU supports 4K60 H.265/H.264/VP9 video decoder, 1080P60 H.264/H.265 video encoder.

I installed their recommended system (Debian 11(Bullseye) Core, without GUI, Kernel 5.10.110), then `ffmpeg` with `apt`.

I wish to decode a 4K HEVC video to lower resolution FHD, H264 as fast as possible.

But I couldn't even enable HW accelerated decoding:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -i mysource.mp4 -f null - -benchmark
...
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x55beea4260] Cannot open the X11 display .
....
[hevc @ 0x55beeb7570] Auto hwaccel disabled: no device found.
```

Fps is around 1.x, which is way too slow.

How can I use the marketed HW acceleration with FFMPEG on this CPU?

Comment: You can utilize the hardware function units using the [Rockchip Media Processing Platform](https://github.com/rockchip-linux/mpp).

Comment: I tried to build ffmpeg-rk (https://github.com/jjm2473/ffmpeg-rk), but I always get `Failed to initialize MPP context (code = -1).` errors